# Angular How do you know when Authentication Status changed?

Tags: angular, authentication, observable, subscription

Im currently working on a webapp with a login. But I have a problem with the Logout Button. The Logout Button is only supposed to show when you are logged in and vanish when you logout.

Thats my Button (menu-items.component):

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn" (click)="onLogout()">Logout</li>
</ul>
```

Code (menu-items.component):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../../http.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-items',
  templateUrl: './menu-items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-items.component.css']
})
export class MenuItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  onSignout(){
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  }
}
```

Basically when I login I want "isLoggedIn" to be "true".

Login Part (login.component):

```
 onSignin(){

    const username = this.loginForm.get('username').value;
    const password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;

    this.httpServie.sendDataLogin("grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
         this.token = JSON.parse(data["_body"]).access_token
         this.username = JSON.parse(data["_body"]).userName
         localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({username: this.username, token: this.token}))

        },
        err => {
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {

            this.ServerErrorMsg = err.error.message;
          } else {

            const returnArray = [];
            this.ServerErrorMsg = JSON.parse(err._body).error_description + "\n";
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

The Login Part is working! Im sending my data to my API and in return im getting my Token.

But the thing is how do I tell my isLoggedIn boolean that im logged in now? I think I need an observable or something to listen to with subscribe, right? 
Im new to Angular and I dont really understand observables. Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you forgot to update your isLoggedIn variable after successfully logging in.

Try this

```
subscribe(
    data => {
     this.token = JSON.parse(data["_body"]).access_token
     this.username = JSON.parse(data["_body"]).userName
     localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({username: this.username, token: this.token}))
this.isLoggedIn=true;
}
```

Comment: isLoggedIn is in "menu-items.component" but the onSingin function is in the "login-component"

Comment: Ah OK sorry missed that bit. In that case is login component a child of menu component? Or they are completely detached?

Comment: completely detached

Comment: In that case either you have a generic service that handles events or you have a service used by these two components and one emits the value and the other subscribed to it.

Comment: Ah okey but how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

what i suggest to you is to do in your service (better) or in your component (no so better) one getter method like:

private _isLogged:boolean =false;

```
isLoggedIn(){

 var local= localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
var token= JSON.Parse(local) as any;

return local && token && token.access_token;
}
onSignin(){

    const username = this.loginForm.get('username').value;
    const password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;

    this.httpServie.sendDataLogin("grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
         this.token = JSON.parse(data["_body"]).access_token
         this.username = JSON.parse(data["_body"]).userName
         localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({username: this.username, token: this.token}));
```

this._isLogged = true; //<-- sei it to true

```
        },
        err => {
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {

            this.ServerErrorMsg = err.error.message;
          } else {

            const returnArray = [];
            this.ServerErrorMsg = JSON.parse(err._body).error_description + "\n";
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

then in your code :

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn()" (click)="onLogout()">Logout</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. 
can u explain that with more detail? 
I created the function isLoggedIn in my http.service.
But i dont really understand the rest u said ^^ 
And i think u cant ngIf with a function thats not in the same component right?

And Login and Logout functions arent on the same component

Comment: I forgot that return button = add comment ^^ read my first comment again plz